# ¡Sobre DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP!

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes a todos de nuevo,
Chicos ahora ando peleando con insertar por default la fecha en una tabla de mi mySql. Tabla Cita. Claro que el cliente no tiene porque ingresar la fecha, pero a mi SI me interesa saber cuando ingresó la solicitud de cita.

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas realizado un query para crear tu table, puedes crear el campo de esta forma en mySql:

```
 create table Cita(campotimestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

de esta forma tendrás como default el actual timestamp.

Para más detalles puedes revisar la documentación:

[Inicialización automática y actualización para TIMESTAMP y DATETIME.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) (inglés).

Answer (score 1):

Con esto:

```
$fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = "INSERT INTO usuario (...,...,fecha...)....VALUES  ('".$fecha_registro."',....)
```

Solo agrégale otro campo mas a tu bd y en la inserción en tu PHP añádale la fecha. En MySQL el tipo sería `datetime`